# Splide Slider - Making a responsive slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit - it actually works, just need to refresh it when emulating a mobile phone. :D

---

I have this kind of code, but the result is that it always shows 3 items per page instead of one on the small devices.

```
<script>
        
   
        
    if (window.screen.width >= 750) {
      document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            new Splide( '.splide', {
                perPage: 3,
                focus  : 'center',
                rewind : true,
            } ).mount();
        } );
    } else {
        document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            new Splide( '.splide', {
                perPage: 1,
                focus  : 'center',
                rewind : true,
            } ).mount();
        } );
    }
        
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit - it actually works, just need to refresh it when emulating a mobile phone. :D